# Appear this.state on Alert by React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating an App using `React-Native`.
I want to display what the user entered in the `alert`.
This is to notify that the content entered by the user has been saved in the system.

How can I get the alert to display `this.state.text` in the code below?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Alert, Button, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Text extends Component{
  state = {
    text: ""
  };
  handleTextChange = text =>{
    this.setState({text});
  };
  handleButtonPress(){
    Alert.alert(
      '保存しました!!',
      //I want to appear this.state.text here
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>URL:&nbsp;{this.state.text}</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder='Textを入力してください' onChangeText={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.text} />
        <Button title='保存する' onPress={this.handleButtonPress}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please lend me your strength.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways you can achieve this,

**1. Use an arrow function**

```js
handleButtonPress = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    '保存しました!!',
    this.state.text
  );
};
```

**2. Bind your (non-arrow) function, you just have to do either 1 of the following choices**

```js
//choice 1: Bind on constructor
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this)
}

handleButtonPress(){
  Alert.alert(
    '保存しました!!',
    this.state.text
  );
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>URL:&nbsp;{this.state.text}</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder='Textを入力してください' onChangeText={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.text} />
//Choice 2: Bind it everytime you call the function
      <Button title='保存する' onPress={this.handleButtonPress.bind(this)}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: My problem was solved  for `1. Use an arrow function`.  Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do change like below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Alert, Button, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Text extends Component{
  state = {
    text: ""
  };
  handleTextChange = text =>{
    this.setState({text:text});  //////change here
  };
  handleButtonPress(){
    Alert.alert(this.state.text); ////////////show text from state
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>URL:&nbsp;{this.state.text}</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder='Textを入力してください' onChangeText={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.text} />
        <Button title='保存する' onPress={this.handleButtonPress}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```